# Wordpress: if post is in category display nav menu

Tags: php, wordpress

How to display different navigation menu based on  **"in what category post is"** ?

I have 2 categories:

- **address** (link: www.sitename.com/address/)
- **info** (link: www.sitename.com/info/)

And I have 3 navigation menu:

- **navmenu0();** (this menu should be used if "post" is in no category)
- **navmenu1();** (this menu should be used if "post" is in category
  "**address**")
- **navmenu2();** (this menu should be used if "post" is in category "**info**")

this is the code that I use in header:

```
    <nav id="menu" role="navigation">

        <?php if (is_category('info')) {
            navmenu2();
        } else if (is_category('address')) {
            navmenu1();
        } else { 
            navmenu0();
        } ?>

    </nav>
```

Problem is when I open post from category "info", the **"if"** those not work and it show "**navmenu0();**" instead of showing **"navmenu2();"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `in_category()` instead of `is_category()`:

```
if (in_category('info')) {
   navmenu2();
} else if (in_category('address')) {
   navmenu1();
} else { 
   navmenu0();
}
```

Reference: [in_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

Comment: @Art-of-Life - But, have you tried `in_category()` instead of `is_category()`. The later seems to be wrong codex since you wan't to know if the current post belongs to a category. Perhaps you should also try to regenerate your permalinks.

Comment: yes I try in_category. Not working. How to regenerate your permalinks. I`m a new to php. Can you edit code, please. This is test site: [link](http://gs.comit.co.rs/de/home/)

Comment: I found out that for in_category to be able to work category name and it`s slug must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that for in_category to be able to work category name and it`s slug must be the same.